# Approaching of area and perimeter of a regular polygon to that of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons

When regular polygon approaches to circle its area and perimeter also approaches to that of a circle.
Can you graphically show that ?

Comment: This is Archimedes' famous Method of Exhaustion. You can see a graphic representation of this method on the relevant Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion

Comment: BTW, this question is not about graph theory :)

Answer (score 1):

Play with this flash application: http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonregular.html

Click "More" to increase the number of vertices.

Comment: can you collect maximum number of proofs on that subject.